# UserManager.GetUserName(User) return NULL after successful login

Tags: .net-core

My code was working before but after optimization, the code doesn't work and since yesterday I am trying to figure out what is the problem...
The issue is, I can't get username in my _Layout page after a successful login. UserManager keeps returning null.

**In My Startup **

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
       services.AddDefaultIdentity<AppUser>(config => { config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true; }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppIdentityDbContext>();
       ...........
       services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseSession();
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
        });
    }
```

**AccountController**

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)    
 {
       await signInManager.SignOutAsync();
       AppUser user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);

        if (user != null)
        {
            await signInManager.SignOutAsync();
            var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, model.Password, false, false);

             if (result.Succeeded){ return Redirect("/Home");}
  }
```

In Account controller user successfully logs in and I call the Home index page. In my _Layout i would like to show the user name in my navigation bar.

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
 @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
 @inject SignInManager<AppUser> SignInManager
 @inject UserManager<AppUser> UserManager

  @if (UserManager.GetUserName(User) == null)
  {
      <a class="btn btn-warning"
         asp-action="Login" asp-controller="Account">Log In</a>
  }
  else
  {
       <a class="btn  btn-danger"
          asp-action="Logout" asp-controller="Account">Log Out(@UserManager.GetUserName(User))</a>
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I am new to .net core and I didn't know in startup class the order of apps are important.
As soon as I moved the app.UseAuthentication(); to the top part of the Configure Method, everything starts working. It doesn't make sense to me but it fixed my issue.